# Tkinter - Unable to get value from a global var set by another method

Tags: python, tkinter, text

I'm trying to get the value of global var saved inserted into my text box but for some unknown reason, even though saved is a global var, it can only be displayed inside the method which assigns the value (string).

```py
note = Text(root)
note.place(relx=0.1,rely=0.65, relwidth=0.85, relheight=0.3)

global saved
def save_note(note):
    try:
        saved = note.get(1.0, END) # No problem!
        messagebox.showinfo("Success!", saved)
    except:
        messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Can't save")

def get_note(note):
    try:
        note.insert(index=END, chars=saved) # Problem?!
    except:
        messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Can't get notes")
```

Below are the buttons that use the commands save_note and get_note

```py
button16 = Button(root, text="SAVE", bg='white', fg='black', command=lambda:save_note(note))
button16.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.65, relwidth=0.04, relheight=0.15)

button17 = Button(root, text="Get", bg='white', fg='black', command=lambda:get_note(note))
button17.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.80, relwidth=0.04, relheight=0.15)
```

In this line of code, I could not insert into the text box the value of saved

```py
note.insert(index=END, chars=saved) # Problem?!
```

I have tried saved.get(), after failing to apply some OOP. I have checked the value of saved var by

```py
messagebox.showinfo("Success!", saved)
```

and there was no problem - saved contains everything I typed in.
[image]

Could you suggest a solution to this issue I'm facing?
[image]
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is because the method `save_note` creates a new local variable instead of updating the local variable `saved`

Your code should be :

```
def save_note(note):
    global saved
    try:
        saved = note.get(1.0, END) # No problem!
        messagebox.showinfo("Success!", saved)
    except:
        messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Can't save")

def get_note(note):
    global saved
    try:
        note.insert(index=END, chars=saved) # Problem?!
    except:
        messagebox.showinfo("Error", "Can't get notes")
```

The global keyword is used to import a global var locally or create a global var if it does not exist.

Comment: Thank you very much this answers my question! I did not expect global var to be like this :0